# Set relations on two fields related to the same table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have a `users` table with many users, for example:

```
id | name
1  | mike
2  | nina
3  | john
```

I also have a `posts` table with a `user_id` that represents the original creator of the post and a `locked_user_id` that is filled if the post was locked by an editor.

Any user can lock or open the post but if the post is locked only that user can edit it. This are my relations:

User model:

```
public function posts(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
}
```

Post model:

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

And I can retrieve the author easily by

```
$posts->user->name
```

I would like to be able to get both the original creator user and the editor. For instance, a sample of the post table:

```
| id | user_id |    post    | locked_user_id |
| 1  |    1    |  blah blah |       2        |
```

In this case `$posts->user->name` returns *mike* but I want to be able to get the user *nina* which is currently locking the post.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `locked_user_id` can be null, and, if so, the returned user is based on the `used_id`, you could update the `user()` relation on the `Post` model to:

```
public function user()
{
    if (!is_null($this->locked_user_id)) {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'locked_user_id', 'id');
    }

    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

So, if there's a `locked_user_id` the returned used is based on this field, otherwise the returned user is based on the `user_id` field

---

As per the comment, if you want to access both users, you can add another relation on the `Post` model. For instance

```
// Assuming `user_id` is not nullable, this will always return the original user
public function creator()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}

// Assuming `locked_user_id` is nullable, this will return either `null`, if there is no editor or the user that locked the post
public function editor()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'locked_user_id', 'id');
}
```

On your code you can do something like:

```
if (is_null($this->editor)) {
    dd('There is no editor');
} elseif ($this->editor->id === $this->creator->id) {
    dd('The original creator has locked the post');
} else {
    dd('The post was created by ' . $this->creator->name. ' but now is locked by ' . $this->editor->name);
}
```

Comment: but the user_id is alway the author. which is fixed for the first guy who originally creates the post. so in a case where locked user is not the original user. i want both the names returned.

Comment: @MohamedAthif You can't do that with a single relation. The best solution is to have two relations, one for the creator and another for the editor (which might return null).

Comment: how do i make two relations for one post? post to user? would that not make doubles ?

Comment: @MohamedAthif Updated answer with both relations and example code. To answer your edited comment, no, it does not "make duplicates". You simply have two fields related to the same table, hence two relations.

Comment: had to tinker the if code a bit :) but the relation works perfect and does the job. thank you